# How to upload file to Oracle DB as Blob/Clob using Helidon MP REST Services

Tags: java, oracle, rest, file, helidon

I am new to Helidon MP and would like to know if there is a way to upload files to Oracle DB (Blob/Clob Column) via REST service created using Helidon MP.

I am able to acheive the same requirement in SpringBoot using below code accepting the file parameter as MultiPart, how can we acheive this using Helidon MP

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
      public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String message = "";
        try {
          storageService.store(file);

          message = "Uploaded the file successfully: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
          return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          message = "Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
          return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
        }
      }
```

Comment: From the "About" page: "*Helidon is a collection of Java libraries for writing microservices...*" So of course there is a way to do it, but you need to provide more details of what did you try and what was wrong with your code/attempts.

Comment: Hi i have done the same requirement using SpringBoot and i could acheive the same by accepting the parameter as MultipartFile and do the corresponding processing for the same. In Helidon MP i am not sure how would we accept the file as @RequestParam is a SpringBoot component.Below code shows how i have acheived the same using SpringBoot

Comment: public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
     String message = "";
     try {
       storageService.store(file);

       message = "Uploaded the file successfully: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
     } catch (Exception e) {
       message = "Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
     }
   }

Comment: Please, add this information to the question via [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65075371/edit), not to comments.

Answer (score 0):

*Helidon* offers support for *multi-part* data through both *MP* and *SE* (with buffered and streamed API version for *SE*) flavors.

The implementation relies on *Jersey* Integration with MIME MultiPart messages (would be quite similar to any *JAX-RS* provider).

An implementation of a controller endpoint method allowing to upload files is straightforward and looks like below:

```
import import javax.ws.rs.*;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.*;

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(MultiPart multiPart) throws IOException {

    multiPart.getBodyParts().stream()
            .filter(part -> /* retrieve your file part here, should be based on the `Content-Disposition` name parameter */ )
            .map(filePart -> {
                String fileName  = pfilePartart.getContentDisposition().getFileName();
                InputStream is = filePart.getEntityAs(BodyPartEntity.class).getInputStream();
                // use the injected `storageService` to somehow store the input stream
                this.storageService.store(fileName, is);
            });
    
}
```

Note that the *JAX-RS* multi-part feature is not activated by default, hence should be activated using *JAX-RS* providers:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class MultiPartFeatureProvider implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        return new MultiPartFeature().configure(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: You made a little error in your class name. This example is how it should be done:
https://github.com/oracle/helidon/blob/2.3.2/examples/microprofile/multipart/src/main/java/io/helidon/examples/microprofile/multipart/MultiPartFeatureProvider.java

Note; the Jersey multipart dependency is required in the pom.xml